# Can i set padding to ExpandableListView and mantain a textview on each child?

Tags: android, textview, expandablelistview, padding

EDIT: can I do something like this...

```
    public View getChildView(int i, int i2, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if(view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_layout, null);
    }

    if(i2 == 3) {
        view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 20);
    } else {
        view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(child.get(i).get(i2));
    tv.setPadding(30, 10, 10, 10);
    tv.setTextSize(25);
    return view;
}
```

...and still get the text to display && keeping the padding.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused at what the context of your question is...

Comment: @AlexK, I wish to set a padding to the last child in an expandablelistview all the while retaining a textview that I will place at that child. The problem that I am experiencing is the fact that I can only return one view- what I want to do requires a return of view and tv respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you can return many view from your adapter. As well, you could define a specific view for every line.

Please see my article: http://raverat.github.io/android-listview-multi-views/

Even if this is for a simple ListView, I guess it's the same for an ExpandableListView! ;)